# Proper morphism induces a map between compact support etale cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $f : Y \to X$ be a proper morphism between noetherian separated schemes of finte type (over a noetherian scheme $S$), and $\mathscr{F}$ a sheaf on the small etale site on $X$.
Then does $f$ induce $f : H_c^i(X, \mathscr{F}) \to H_c^i (Y, f^* \mathscr{F})$?

The compact support cohomology is not a derived functor.
So the canonical map between $H_c^0$ does not induce maps of $\delta$-functors.

Here's what I tried so far: Let $j : X \to \overline{X}$ be a compactification. Then since $f$ is separated and of finite type, $j \circ f$ is so. Therefore there is a compactification $i : Y \to \overline{Y}$ over $\overline{X}$. (Nagata compactification)
So we have a commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Y @>{i}>> \overline{Y}\\
@V{f}VV @V{\overline{f}}VV\\
X @>{j}>> \overline{X}
\end{CD}
Now $H_c^i(X, \mathscr{F}) = H^i(\overline{X}, j_!\mathscr{F}), H_c^i (Y, f^* \mathscr{F}) = H^i(\overline{Y}, i_! f^*\mathscr{F})$.
But since the diagram is not Cartesian, it seems that $i_!f^* \neq \overline{f}^*j_!$.
And even if these two coincide, since $j_!$ does not takes injectives to injectices, the canonical map between $H^0$ does not induce the required maps.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two concerns :

- How to define the base-change map
- How to extend the base-change from the cohomological degree $0$ to the degree $n$

Let me answer first the second concern. If you are familiar with total derived functor, then this can be answer really easily. By adjunction, there is a natural morphism $\mathcal{F}\to R\overline{f}_*\overline{f}^*\mathcal{F}$ in $D(\overline{X}_{et})$. There is also a natural identification $H^*(\overline{X},R\overline{f}_*\mathcal{G})=H^*(\overline{Y},\mathcal{G})$ for any $\mathcal{G}\in D(\overline{Y})$. Composing these two, we get the usual pullback in cohomology :
$$ H^*(\overline{X},\mathcal{F})\to H^*(\overline{X},R\overline{f}_*\overline{f}^*\mathcal{F})=H^*(\overline{Y},\overline{f}^*\mathcal{F})$$
From this, assuming we have our base-change map $(*)$, we can define :
$$H^*_c(X,\mathcal{F})=H^*(\overline{X},j_!\mathcal{F})\to H^*(\overline{X},R\overline{f}_*\overline{f}^*j_!\mathcal{F})= H^*(\overline{Y},\overline{f}^*j_!\mathcal{F})\overset{(*)}\to H^*(\overline{Y}, i_!f^*\mathcal{F})=H^*_c(Y,f^*\mathcal{F})$$

So, the first concern remains : we have to construct the map $(*)$, or rather the map $\overline{f}^*j_!\to i_!f^*$. Consider $Y'=X\times_{\overline{X}}\overline{Y}$, so we have the commutative diagram :
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y@>i_1>>Y'@>i_2>>\overline{Y}\\
@VfVV@VVf'V@VV\overline{f}V\\
X@=X@>>j>\overline{X}
\end{CD}$$
With $i=i_2i_1$ and $f=f'i_1$. So we have :
$$\overline{f}^*j_!\overset{(1)}\simeq {i_2}_!f'^*\overset{(2)}\to {i_2}_!{i_1}_!i_1^*f'^*=i_!f^*$$
Where :

- the isomorphism labelled $(1)$ follows from base change isomorphism induced by the right square, which is cartesian.
- the morphism labelled $(2)$ follows from the unit of adjunction $1\to {i_1}_*i_1^*={i_1}_!i_1^*$ because $i_1$ is a closed immersion (this is where we use the properness of $f$. We have indeed $f=f'i_1$, therefore, since $f$ is proper, so is $i_1$. Because $i_1$ is clearly a quasi-finite, this is a closed immersion).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't know where you use the properness of $f$ in the second concern.

Comment: @k.j. Yes I should have mentioned it. This is when I said that $i_1$ is a closed immersion (I used that $f'i_1=f$ is proper so $i_1$ is proper). I'll edit my post.

Comment: I could understand it. Excuse me, but may I ask you the second concern?

Comment: @k.j. What do you mean ? My answer is not clear ?

Comment: "$i_1$ is a closed immersion, so..." is what you said the first concern.
In the second concern the word "proper" does not appear.

Comment: Sorry I still cannot understand your comment. What I said in the first part of my answer does not use the fact that $f$ is proper. This is only a very general functoriality argument.

Comment: So do you mean that there always exists the canonical maps between $H^i_c$?
In my text book (Milne's Etale Cohomology), the author says "there do not exist unless $f$ is proper".
Sorry, this is maybe a misunderstanding.
I'm not familiar with the total derived functors.

Comment: @k.j. No this is not what I am saying. Even in the case $i=0$ there is no pullback map in cohomology with proper support. I used the fact that $f$ is proper to have the map labelled $(2)$. Without this assumption, this map might not exists. The first part of the post explained how to extend the base change map from the cohomological degree $0$ to a general degree $i$. This does not require $f$ to be proper, but require the base change map to exist.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's very what I wanted to know. I'm not familiar with total derived functors, but anyway your "second concern" helps me so much! I appreciate your kindness.